# What determines dir order or default order in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, dir

I'm loading up a thumbdrive with music for my car.  The folders play out of order.  I did a  "dir" of the folders from command line, and the order matches - but neither is alphabetical.  Windows Explorer shows them in alphabetical order.

1. Why is this?
2. How did this happen?
3. How do I fix?

Here's what I get when I type "dir" from the command line (not including full folder names).  My first thought was something screwy with the 8.3, but it's out of order too.

> Adebisi Sh
>    Anathema-W
>    Chrome Hoo
>    cloudkicke
>    Echolyn-Ec
>    Magma - Em
>    Red Sparow
>    Rocky's Fi
>    SKE - 1000
>    wobbler -
>    Porcupine
>    Blackfield
>    Anglagard
>    Nicklas Ba
>    Uzva-Uoma
>    Sanhedrin
>    Russian Ci
>    Return To

Comment: I just used `dir` on the command line on my Windows 7 computer, and it's in alphabetical order.

Comment: Short answer: "dir" shows the raw order in the file system. Different file systems have different raw orders. Explorer sorts them.

Comment: Wow - talk about getting an answer from the source! Thanks!  It's using NTFS on Win7 x64.  I tried creating new folders to put the files in, and I think it's using creation date plus name - all the new folders are at the end. Back to the main question - short of making new folders and dropping the files in there, is there a easy way to set them up?  Thanks, but I think I may have a workaround.

Comment: This is not about programming. You can find the explanation in Raymond Chen's blog: [What order does the DIR command arrange files if no sort order is specified?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=1603). Cross-site duplicate: [Default file order of "dir" command in Windows console](https://superuser.com/q/481570/241386). There are various tools for reordering purpose in car mp3 players that you can find in my answer there